# If $x\mapsto \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - 2f(x) +f(x-h)}{h^2}$ is continuous, then $f\in C^2$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> Let $a<b$ and $f:(a,b)\to \mathbb R$ be continuous and such that for all $x\in (a,b)$,  $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - 2f(x) +f(x-h)}{h^2}$ exists. Let $\beta:x\mapsto \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - 2f(x) +f(x-h)}{h^2}$. If $\beta$ is continuous over $(a,b)$, prove that $f\in C^2((a,b))$ (i.e. $f$ is twice continuously differentiable)

I'm aware that if $f$ is twice differentiable, then $\beta = f''$. I'm also aware that the mere existence of $\beta$ does not guarantee that $f$ is twice differentiable. The strong assumption in this problem is that $\beta$ be continuous. The continuity assumption on $f$ should also come into play somewhere...

I've seen this problem asked at an oral exam and I find it quite interesting. I've been thinking about it for a few days but I have made zero progress towards a solution ...

Comment: As you mention, the continuity assumption on $f$ is necessary because otherwise any additive ($\mathbb Q$-linear) function $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ has $\beta=0$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Use a Rolle's theorem style argument to show that if $\beta$ is a positive constant then $f$ cannot have a local maximum in $(a,b).$ Use this to show that $f$ is affine if $\beta$ is identically zero. Use this to show that $f\in C^2$ for general $\beta.$

Comment: Could you please explain it a little bit more?! It's hard for me to proceed...

Comment: @SubhasisBiswas: I suggest asking another question if there's a point you're stuck on. A slightly stronger proposition is Corollary 5.33 in "Symmetric Properties of Real Functions" by Brian Thomson https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=BMWk0X8rl_YC&lpg=PA205&ots=SI_HAEH5T8&dq=Symmetric%20Properties%20of%20Real%20Functions%20corollary%205.33&pg=PA205#v=onepage&q=Symmetric%20Properties%20of%20Real%20Functions%20corollary%205.33&f=false

Comment: Thanks for responding!!! I checked out your link. And I think it will take some time for me to grasp this. Thank you very much.